# SessionとCacheの使い分けがわかりません

Tags: php, laravel, redis

Laravel5を使用してWebアプリケーションを実装しています。

初回アクセスは外部サイトのAPIで取得した情報をRedisに保存して、すべてのアクセスユーザーが毎回APIを叩かなくてもいいようにしようと思っています。

ただ、SessionでもCacheでもRedisに保存できるようなのですが、どういうふうに使い分けるのかがわかりません。

どのような用途で分けるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SessionとCacheは用途が違います。
やりたいことを実現するためにどちらもRedisという技術を使いますが、用途が違うため利用場面は変わってきます。

Session
主にブラウザが閉じるまで維持されるデータです。
データのアクセス権限としてはサーバとブラウザでセッションIDをやり取りするため、ブラウザまたいだデータの流用はできません。一ブラウザで一セッションが基本です。
利用例としては
ログインの維持、ECサイトのカート機能

Cache
基本的に明示的にクリアしない限り維持されるデータです。
データのアクセス権限はどこからでも可能です。アプリケーション側で制約をしない限りCacheにつながる人であれば誰でも利用できます。
利用例としては
重いSQLクエリ結果のキャッシュ

Comment: ありがとうございます！私のやりたいこととしては、Cacheになりますね。やってみます